# SwiftyJson Cannot set value

Tags: json, swift, sorting, alamofire

Im using Alamofire to get a table of trucks. Results are handled using SwiftyJSON. One of the columns is the coordinate of each truck.

I would like to compare the trucks coordinate with the users current location. I can already do the calculation. I was thinking of adding the distance calculated into the same JSONObject as a new field with the intention of sorting by distance but I cant seem to set a new value at all.

Setting a json object is not working at all. Below is my code. I commented the part where it doesnt work. I dont get warnings or errors. If i print that out i just get a blank row. Please help. Thanks in advance. Am I doing it right? Any suggestions on how I could best sort the list by distance given the truck coordinates in the results and user location on device?

```
 Alamofire.request(.POST, Ftf.endPoint(), parameters: params).responseJSON { response in

        if response.result.value != nil{
            let obj = JSON(response.result.value!)
            self.jsonObj = obj
            //ATTEMPT TO SORT THE JSON OBJECT
            print("Begin Sorting Object")
            print("User located at \(self.MyLocation)")

            for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in self.jsonObj {
                let truckloc = subJson["truckLocation"].stringValue
                print("This truck is at \(truckloc)")

                let coords = truckloc
                var coord = coords.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
                let lat = coord[0]
                let lon = coord[1]
                let truckLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((lat as NSString).doubleValue, (lon as NSString).doubleValue)
                let point1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.MyLocation)
                let point2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(truckLocation)
                let distance = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(point1, point2)/1000
                let distanceStr = NSString(format: "%.1f", distance)

                print("Distance of truck from user is \(distanceStr)")

                //THIS LINE HERE DOESNT WORK. NO ERROR NO WARNINGS. JUST NOTHING HAPPENS
                self.jsonObj[key]["distance"].string = "\(distanceStr)"


            }

            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.ftfRefresh.endRefreshing()
        }else{
            self.presentViewController(Ftf.generalAlert("No network connection found"), animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `self.jsonObj[key]["distance"] = "\(distanceStr)"`

Comment: Yes. If I do it that way, I get a "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'JSON'. Didnt work.

Comment: Maybe `self.jsonObj[key]["distance"] as! String = "\(distanceStr)"`

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

self.jsonObj[key]["distance"] = JSON("\(distanceStr)")

Sample example,

```
    var json = JSON(["1":"2"])

    print(json)

    json["1"] = JSON("3")

    print(json)
```

Comment: It says Cannot invoke initializer for type 'JSON' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Answer (score 0):

I havent figured out why, but I seem to have fixed my issue. Insted of using self.jsonObj, I used a local obj and added the field. When done i updated the global self.jsonObj. The following code worked. Also key was passed as a string. I changed it to an Int

```
 Alamofire.request(.POST, Ftf.endPoint(), parameters: params).responseJSON { response in

        if response.result.value != nil{
            var obj = JSON(response.result.value!)
                            //ATTEMPT TO SORT THE JSON OBJECT
            print("Begin Sorting Object")
            print("User located at \(self.MyLocation)")

            for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in obj {
                let truckloc = subJson["truckLocation"].stringValue
                print("This truck is at \(truckloc)")

                let coords = truckloc
                var coord = coords.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
                let lat = coord[0]
                let lon = coord[1]
                let truckLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((lat as NSString).doubleValue, (lon as NSString).doubleValue)
                let point1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.MyLocation)
                let point2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(truckLocation)
                let distance = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(point1, point2)/1000
                let distanceStr = NSString(format: "%.1f", distance)

                print("Distance of truck from user is \(distanceStr)")

                //FINALLY IT WORKED

                obj[Int(key)!]["dist"].stringValue = distanceStr as String
                print(obj[Int(key)!]["dist"].stringValue)


            }

            self.jsonObj = obj



            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.ftfRefresh.endRefreshing()
        }else{
            self.presentViewController(Ftf.generalAlert("No network connection found"), animated: true, completion: nil)
        }




    }
```